# AppEngine: IOError when saving a lot of objects to the Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, binary-tree

Cheers all. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and the latest Google AppEngine SDK. I'm working on a simple website which has posts and comments to posts. I basically implemented a simple tree to store my comments with a `parent_comment`, `left` and `right` values.

I created an event which fires before a new (`not is_saved()`) comment is `put()` into the Google Datastore, which calculates the `left` and `right` values for the new comment, as well as updates older comments for a valid hierarchy. I basically followed [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and implemented it in Python.

Everything seems to work fine, new comments are added, threading looks good, but...
A cycle that submits 40 comments during startup works, but when I increase that cycle to 80 or more, I'm left with an IOError:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmp0agXqU'
```

My code for generating 60 comments looks like this:

```
for k in range(0, 4):
    comments = {0: None}
    for i in range(1, 21):
        j = random.randrange(0, len(comments))
        pc = comments[j]

        comments[i] = Comment(
            name=lipsum(count=1),
            email=lipsum(count=1, make_slug=True) + '@email.com',
            url='http://' + lipsum(count=2, make_slug=True) + '.com',
            content=lipsum(count=random.randrange(10, 50)),
            object_link=p.key(),
            parent_comment=pc
        )
        comments[i].put()
```

The `lipsum` function simply returns a piece of lorem ipsum text.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem for a massive taskqueue worker.

Switching to [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) for your local Datastore could solve the problem:

```
dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite
```

> Since App Engine SDK 1.3.3, the Python
>   SDK has a new experimental feature
>   that gives  the option to use SQLite
>   as the datastore stub backend. Using
>   SQLite within the dev_appserver should
>   speed up performance of your local
>   datastore when testing on large
>   datasets.

For the `dev_appserver` documentation, have a look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to a [bug in latest App Engine SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3907). The comments of the bug report provide a patch that fixes the issue.